# Modify the value of $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] via .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, document-root

Can I use **.htaccess** to change the return value of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` for local development only?

Currently, `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` returns,

```
C:\wamp\www
```

but I want it to return this,

```
C:\wamp\www\website_folder
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Can't you just change the document root in the central configuration?

Comment: Make sure your apache configuration is correct. Check the `DocumentRoot` in the vhost section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] returns the document route as defined in your server's config. I think you use http://localhost/website_folder (or host.com/website_folder) to access the site.

It doesn't return the website folder. 
You can create a new virtual host and set its document route to the appropriate folder, failin that, you cannot. Frankly, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. IF you want the website path, you can always use

```
$serverPath=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/website_folder"
```